# URL redirection

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have following code written for lightning component

here is my condition the condition works fine but it gives me response as Visit Baidu! link
iam stucked here i want to redirect this to particular URL rather than giving me link, Is their anyway so that i can skip this link and it will redirect to the URL directly without giving me link

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!con.BillingCountry =='China'}">
          <a href="https://map.baidu.com"> Visit baidu!</a>   
        </aura:if>
```

Please help here iam stuck in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect the user based on `<aura:if>` markup logic. You'll need to implement logic in your JavaScript controller. You can use the [`<lightning:navigation>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) component to request navigation to an external website.

Declare it in your markup:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

Then use a [`pageReference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_web_page.htm) to request navigation to a web page, from your JavaScript controller:

```
component.find("navService").navigate({ 
    type: "standard__webPage", 
    attributes: { 
        url: 'https://map.baidu.com' 
    } 
});
```